# What are the cons and pros of using void * as the this pointer in methods versus my_class * and force casts when calling a parent method?

Tags: c, oop

I'm currently using OOP techniques in C, and I've used the known idiom of a child class having a parent class instance inside its struct, like this:

```
struct parent{
    void (*doSomething)(struct parent *parent);
};

struct child{
    struct parent base;
    int (*doSomethingCooler)(struct child *child);
};
```

Now, my methods are prefixed with the class they belong to:

```
void parent_doSomething(struct parent *parent);
int child_doSomethingCooler(struct child *child);
```

With overloading, I have

```
void child_doSomethingCool(struct parent *parent);
```

that I set to parent->doSomething on the child constructor function.

Anyway, the problem arises when I have a child instance, and I want to call parent methods. Immediately, I have to cast (sort of dynamic_cast in C) my instance pointer to the parent class type, and this fastly pollutes my code.

The second idea was to define all methods to receive void * "this" parameters, and internally cast them to the right class. This simplifies the usage from client code, but expose the code to nasty bugs, like passing invalid references, or references of the wrong type.

What are the pros and cons of each implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new type generic feature of C11 you could uniformly access the parent part:

```
#define getParent(X)        \
_Generic((X),               \
    parent*: (X),           \
    child*: (&(X)->base)))
```

and then you could overload your function name with a macro

```
#define doSomething(X) doSomething(getParent(X))
```

as you can see from these examples this wouldn't work too well with OO notation of calling a "method" through the pointer such as `p->doSomething()`, but this could be a start.

Comment: I don't use public function pointers on the structs, I rely on public methods.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've thought of was to add a MAGIC WORD to each class, and check for them at runtime. I could avoid the memory waste and processing overhead by guarding this "feature" from compiling on release builds.

This way I can simplify the client code using these classes, and also protect myself from bad code.